# Export customized vagrant

Tags: clone, vagrant, virtualbox

I mounted a vagrant machine several time ago.I have modified some configurations to the VM since the installation and now my co-workers need to use exactly the same VM.

How can I do it ? I would like keep the database i used for my co-workers too if it's possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into VagrantCloud: https://vagrantcloud.com/

I'm using that service to host a customized box for my team.  Started from a vanilla box, customized it to match our environment, then used the "vagrant package" command to create a new *.box file.  You just need to host that file somewhere online, register it with the VagrantCloud service, and you can manage box releases and deployments for your co-workers.  It even notifies them if you update the box.  Pretty nifty.

As far as the DB, if it is in the VM it will get packaged up too.  Might wat to look into providing updated DB files for later since they will get out of date fast, I would imagine.